# Incremental rsync to encrypted APFS USB drive extremely slow

Tags: backup, apfs, rsync

I use rsync to create incremental backups of my backup dir (containing symlinks to all relevant local dirs) to various machines and/or drives:

```
rsync -ivrLtzS --delete-during --progress --link-dest=../latest /home/Backup [target]
```

The command is part of a wrapper script which updates the `latest` symlink after each run to point to the most recent target dir.

The backup contains ~ 150.000 files and takes ~ 20 GB of disk space. Backing up incrementally to a server (via ssh) or to a local (encrypted) disk image takes between 4 and 10 minutes. But backing up to USB drives (APFS encrypted) took ~ 4 hours for the initial incremental run, and 8 to 12 hours now.

After a quick start, rsync always seems to hang on some random file for hours before finally completing the sync.

Could this be related to APFS/encryption? Or to USB? I recently read about [slow write speeds](https://mjtsai.com/blog/2022/07/06/slow-mac-disk-image-writing/) to disk images, but writing to my encrypted disk image works fine (s. above).

Thanks,
Jan